# Jekyll Collection Not Rendering

Tags: jekyll, liquid, templating

I want to create an archive for old blog posts on my jekyll site. Previously, my structure was serving the contents of `_posts` on my website homepage, index.html. After reading the collections documentation and a few tutorials online, I have added a collection folder `_archive` to my structure and a test file inside called `test-file.markdown.`

However, the url mysite.com/archive/test-file **fully regenerates my main index.html, not the collection contents**.

---

Structure:

```
_archive
    index.html
    test-file.markdown
_includes
    about.html
    head.html
    ... other stuff ...
_layouts
    default.html
_posts
    post1.markdown
    post2.markdown
    ... other stuff ...
css
img
js
_config.yaml
... other stuff ...
```

---

test-file.markdown

```
---
layout: default
title: test
---
```

---

_config.yml

```
# Site settings
title: test
email: test@test.com
url: http://www.test.com


# Color settings (hex-codes without the leading hash-tag)
color:
  primary: ffffff #80B3FF
  primary-rgb: "24,288,156" #"128,179,255"
  secondary: 2c3e50 #FD6E8A
  secondary-dark: 233140 #A2122F
  third: 979797

collections:
  archive:
    output: true
    permalink: /archive/:path/

# Build settings
markdown: kramdown
permalink: pretty
```

---

mysite.com/archive/index.html

```
---
---
{% for p in site.archive %}
  {{ p}}
  {{ p.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

This re-renders the main index.html, not the contents of test-file.markdown.

---

How can I properly render the contents of `_archive` at mysite.com/archive/?

---

EDIT: added `---` to index.html

Answer (score 1):

Did you add the:

```
---
---

{% for p in site.archive %}
{{ p}}
{{ p.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

on the top of the index.html file? If it's missing it won't run any content within in that file through jekyll's templating engine.

Comment: Yes, thank you. The site is still serving the whole of my `_posts` folder into the url: site.com/archive/test/

Comment: Anything else I could be missing here? Thanks @arniekoz for any ideas.

Comment: No, don't wrap the content. But do the edit above @NickB see if it works.

Comment: Thanks but still re-rendering the contents of `_posts`, not `_archive` :(  I think it must be a mistake in config.yml, or general structure? Thanks for any ideas

Comment: I always create layouts for these things. Put the index.html in the layouts dir (as archives.html) and reference it from index.md file. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what your problem really is without seeing the whole site. Provide a repo URL if possible.

---

If the contents of `/index.html` are appearing in the `/_archive/test-file.markdown` output, the post loop is probably in the default layout file, since both of the files share that layout. The solution here would be to move the relevant content into `/index.html`.

---

I believe that your `/_archive/index.html` is not being output. Move `/_archive/index.html` to `/archive.html`. Jekyll doesn't process pages inside of the `_archive` folder because it starts with an underscore.

You'd then have these files output with your current config:

- `/archive/index.html`
- `/archive/test-file/index.html`

---

In my opinion, you should keep posts as posts, whether they are archived or not. You would then keep the URLs when posts are archived rather than having to set 301s or losing them to the great void.

To do this, add front matter to your archived posts:

```
---
archived: true
---
```

And your current posts (you could use [defaults](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/#front-matter-defaults) to save repetition):

```
---
archived: false
---
```

Exclude the archived posts in your main post loop:

```
{% assign posts = site.posts | where: "archived", false %}
```

Exclude the current posts on your archive page:

```
{% assign archived_posts = site.posts | where: "archived", true %}
```